# Kendo control datepicker doesn't understand dateformat in MVVM

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datetimepicker

I have the following code:

```
 <input data-role="datepicker" data-bind="value:referralData.Referral.from_date" />
```

With the value to bind as such:

```
from_date: "2014-01-01T00:00:00"
```

In the object and it doesn't bind anymore.
I have tried:

```
       <input data-role="datepicker" data-bind="value:referralData.Referral.from_date, parseFormats:'YYYY-MM-DD\Thh:mm:ss'" />
```

But it states that: Uncaught Error: The parseFormats binding is not supported by the DatePicker widget. So I believe I have a syntax error that I am missing.

Does anyone know how to tell the datepicker to pick up this date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution by @Lars works, but the date format specifier is wrong (as of Kendo version 2014.3.119). It should be `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` (lower case for year and day and upper case for hour):

```
<input
    data-role="datepicker" 
    data-bind="value:referralData.Referral.from_date" 
    data-parse-formats="yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss" />
```

And as a completion, if sometimes you need to, you can in fact pass more than one format, according to the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker#configuration-parseFormats), like this:

```
<input 
    data-role="datepicker" 
    data-bind="value:referralData.Referral.from_date" 
    data-parse-formats="['yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss','yyyy-MM-dd']" />
```

Answer (score 2):

`data-bind` is for live-binding options. If all you want to do is use the configuration option, you can use `data-parse-formats`:

```
<input data-role="datepicker" 
 data-parse-formats="YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss" 
 data-bind="value:referralData.Referral.from_date" />
```

Also, if you want to use a 24 hour clock, you should use the this formatting config for time: `HH:mm:ss`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom binding for date format:

**Custom Binding**

```
kendo.data.binders.widget.dateFormat = kendo.data.Binder.extend({
  init: function (widget, bindings, options) {
    //call the base constructor
    kendo.data.Binder.fn.init.call(this, widget.element[0], bindings, options);
  },
  refresh: function () {
    var that = this,
      value = that.bindings["dateFormat"].get(); //get the value from the View-Model
    $(that.element).data("kendoDatePicker").setOptions({
      format: value
    }); //update the widget
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="report1" data-role="view" data-model="APP.models.report1">
    <input data-role="datepicker" data-bind="value: start_date, dateFormat: date_format" />
</div>
```

**Model**

```
window.APP = {
  models: {
    report1: kendo.observable({
        start_date: new Date(),
        date_format: "dd/MM/yyyy",
    }),
  }
};

var app = new kendo.mobile.Application($(document.body), {
  initial: "report1",
  skin: "default",
});
```